# Meteor: Check if internet connection exists

Tags: meteor

I have tried using Meteor.status() and it is unreliable. I am using standard Meteor. Is there any way using jQuery or JS to check if the user has a connection to the internet (Just when I am running a function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you mentioned you are using meteor, its safe to assume that you are not even thinking of older browsers like IE 8. Following will work to check if user has active connection or say connected to internet.

`var online = navigator.onLine;`

From [W3C offline web applications](http://www.w3.org/TR/offline-webapps/#related) specs

Comment: BTW why do you need to check if internet connection exists or not, as Meteor itself has first class support for offline with having minimongo at client

Comment: The reason I need to do this is to decide whether to show a mailchimp subscription form. I don't want to show it when the internet connection is down.

Comment: `navigator.onLine` checks only the connectivity to any LAN or Router. So, this is not the foolproof answer to this.

Answer (score 1):

The question has very broad perspective because it would really depend on what you are actually referring to as internet. It could be `connecting to server`, `connecting to just LAN or Router`.

Inside your question I could see you mean "In Meteor, how to check the connectivity to between Client and Server."

Well you can simply use reactive `Meteor.status().status` to track the connectivity status between the Meteor Client and Server.

As per [Documentation for Server Connections](https://docs.meteor.com/api/connections.html#Meteor-status) `status` can be

1. `connected`
2. `connecting`
3. `failed`
4. `waiting`
5. `offline`

I am going to demonstrate a code to show you how to check the Server-Client connectivity status.

**Step 1**

Install package `smowden:offline-js` in your project.

This will give you a view to professionally handle the disconnect situations on UI for your client not to panic.

**Step 2**

Inside **YOUR_PAGE.js**

```
import './YOUR_PAGE.html';

var run = () => {
   // this is supported by smowden:offline-js
   if (Offline.state === 'up'){
      Offline.check();
   }
 }

Template.YOUR_PAGE.onCreated(function(){
  this.isOnline = new ReactiveVar(0);
  this.autorun(() => { 
    // to track status reactively
    if (Meteor.status().status === "connected") {
      console.log('connected.');
       this.isOnline.set(2);
    }
    else if (Meteor.status().status === "connecting") {
      console.log('connecting.');
       this.isOnline.set(1);
    }
    else {
        console.log('not connected.');
        this.isOnline.set(0);
    }
  });
});

Template.YOUR_PAGE.onRendered(function(){
  // run method 'run' at an interval of 5 seconds
  setInterval(run, 5000);
});

Template.YOUR_PAGE.helpers({
  connectivityStatus(statusId){
    // Simple check for equality
    return Template.instance().isOnline.get() == statusId;
  }
});
```

Inside **YOUR_PAGE.html**

```
<template name="YOUR_PAGE">
    <body>
        {{#if connectivityStatus 2}}
            <span class="label label-success">Connected</span>
        {{else}}
          {{#if connectivityStatus 1}}
            <span class="label label-success">Reconnecting</span>
          {{else}}
            <span class="label label-success">Disconnected</span>
          {{/if}}
        {{/if}}
    </body> 
</template>
```

**Step 3**

1. How to check in Development mode? If server is up, simply make some code change and `save`, your UI will reflect changes for various statuses encountered.
2. How to check in Production mode? If server is up, simply pull out `LAN wire`, your UI will reflect changes for various statuses encountered.